# Orthonormal Basis and projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear space of continuous functions $C[−1, +1]$ defined over the interval $[−1, +1]$. We define an inner product $\langle ·, · \rangle$ on $C[−1, +1]$ by
$$\langle f, g \rangle= \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) · g(x) dx, $$ for any $f,g$ in $C[-1, +1]$

a) Consider the linear sub-space $V = Span(x, x^2)$ in $C[−1, +1].$ Find an orthonormal basis of V.

b) Consider the projection $Proj_V: C[−1, +1] \rightarrow V$ . Use the orthonormal basis obtained in (a) to calculate $Proj_V(x^3)$.

I have already answered part a) of which I got ${\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x ,\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}x^2}$ . I am stuck with part b) as I'm thinking there's a formula for this one isn't it? I tried searching in my book but haven't found any. Please help.

Comment: You can project any $f\in C$ onto the subspace spanned by $\{e_{1},e_{2}\}$ by the orthogonal projection $<f,e_{1}>e_{1} + <f,e_{2}>e_{2}.$ Could you fill in the details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection of a vector (in this case $x^3$) into a subspace can be determined by looking at its inner product with all basis vectors in the subspace.

In general, if $w$ is a vector in some vector space $W$, then 
$Proj_V(w) = \sum_i \langle v_i, w\rangle v_i$, where $\{v_i\}$ are the orthonormal basis vectors for $V$.

Since you already have the formula for the inner product and you have calculated an orthonormal basis for $V$, its just a mechanical exercise remaining.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have seen this one but I wasn't sure if I read it right. But thanks! Now I know :)